# Stop Resume Pause IntentService

Tags: android, intentservice

In IntentService When i use stopSelf() it's is working for me like a charm but does it really terminate the current service? And Can we use Pause and Resume our IntentService? if can, how?

Comment: I think that you are misusing IntentService ... it working a  "work queue processor" so it's not for continuous work ... onHandleIntent should ends in some resonable time ... for continuous work use normal service with own background thread

Comment: @Selvin thank! i thought that we can resume or pause

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, it really terminate the current service if it is a normal Service. You can put a log in onDestroy() to see whether the callback is called. In case of IntentService, it will just remove all intents in the queue, and will terminate itself when the current task (current intent) was done.
2. There is no Pause/Resume in IntentService. It is designed to take a task, execute it and terminate right after.

Comment: Why you accepting wrong answer? **No, it obviously will not terminate something running in `onHandleIntent`** while whole service would be terminated  if you have something `while(true) { }` inside `onHandleIntent` it will be not stopped by calling stopSelf